# Iterate through list of objects and transform into an object with nested list of objects

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, javascript-objects

Suppose I have an API that produces a list of objects:

```js
const data = [
    {
        "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
        "visit_status": "Completed",
        "get_year": 2021,
        "get_month": 7
    },
    {
        "get_study_name": "EMBARK",
        "visit_status": "Completed",
        "get_year": 2021,
        "get_month": 7
    },
    {
        "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
        "visit_status": "Completed",
        "get_year": 2020,
        "get_month": 6
    }
]
```

Is it possible to iterate or map through it and produce a result like this?

```
newData: {
    2021: [
       {
          name: 'INFRONT-3', 'EMBARK' //string concatenation of get_study_name
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], //array of months (index +1), and count occurence
          fill: 'start' //inject this on each object
        }
          ],
    2020: [
       {
          name: 'INFRONT-3'
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          fill: 'start'
        }
          ],
}
```

I would really appreciate any tips. I've been stuck for 3 days and the most I can do it get the unique years.

Comment: Have you tried using reduce? If so, may you share that effort?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your comment in the example

> //joined string of get_study_name

is not clear, it doesn't show the string as joined, in fact that line breaks/invalidate the object.
Also it's not clear under what conditions year array should include multiple objects.

```js
const data = [
        {
            "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
            "visit_status": "Completed",
            "get_year": 2021,
            "get_month": 7
        },
        {
            "get_study_name": "EMBARK",
            "visit_status": "Completed",
            "get_year": 2021,
            "get_month": 7
        },
        {
            "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
            "visit_status": "Completed",
            "get_year": 2020,
            "get_month": 6
        }
    ];

const newData = {};
for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++)
{
  const d = data[i],
        obj = (newData[d.get_year] || [{name:'',data:Array(12).fill(0),fill:"start"}])[0];

  obj.name += (obj.name && ", ") + d.get_study_name; // add name
  obj.data[d.get_month-1]++; // increase month count
  newData[d.get_year] = [obj];
}
console.log(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you. I have now edited the comment. It should be concatenation, not join.

Answer (score 0):

```
const newData = {}
data.forEach(d => {
  if (newData[d.get_year]) {
    const datum = newData[d.get_year];
    datum.name += `,${d.get_study_name}`;
    datum.data[d.get_month + 1]++;
  } else {
      newData[d.get_year] = {
          name: d.get_study_name,
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          fill: 'start'
      }
      newData[d.get_year].data[d.get_moth+1]++;
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Here'a one way using a combo of reduce and map.

```js
const data = [{
    "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
    "visit_status": "Completed",
    "get_year": 2021,
    "get_month": 7
  },
  {
    "get_study_name": "EMBARK",
    "visit_status": "Completed",
    "get_year": 2021,
    "get_month": 7
  },
  {
    "get_study_name": "INFRONT-3",
    "visit_status": "Completed",
    "get_year": 2020,
    "get_month": 6
  }
]

let obj = Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(data.reduce((acc, a) => {
  if (!acc.hasOwnProperty(a.get_year)) acc[a.get_year] = [];
  let b = acc[a.get_year]
  let i = b.findIndex(e => e.get_month = a.get_month)
  if (i > -1) {
    b[i].name.push(a.get_study_name);
    b[i].data[a.get_month]++
  } else {
    let cal = Array(12).fill(0);
    cal[a.get_month]++
      b.push({ ...a,
        data: cal,
        name: [a.get_study_name]
      })
  }
  return acc
}, {})).map(d => {
  d[1] = d[1].map(e => {
    delete e.get_study_name;
    delete e.get_month;
    delete e.get_year;
    delete e.visit_status;
    e.fill = 'start';
    e.name = e.name.join(', ')
    return e;
  })
  return d
}))

console.log(obj)
/*
    
    newData: {
    2021: [
       {
          name: 'INFRONT-3', 'EMBARK' //joined string of get_study_name
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], //array of months (index +1), and count occurence
          fill: 'start' //inject this on each object
        }
          ],
    2020: [
       {
          name: 'INFRONT-3'
          data: [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],
          fill: 'start'
        }
          ],
}
*/
```